# Suspending a bash script running in the background

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a bash script running in the background, and it executes in a loop every 5 seconds. This effects the commands that are being executed at the shell itself.

Is there a way, i can suspend the script execution until the shell is not executing other commands.

thanks

Comment: How does it affect the the shell itself? Maybe you just need to redirect the output of the background process?

Answer (score 3):

to stop the scipt you can use

```
kill -s STOP $PID
```

where $PID contains the process ID of the script. To start it again, you use

```
kill -s CONT $PID
```

Answer (score 0):

Renice should help in such scenario. 
Using renice you can decrease/increase the priority of the process. 
Look man page for more detailed help.